# How to resolve the Composer issue when installing dependecy conflicts with the same dependecy?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, composer-php

Have a composer.json file in a project:

```
{
  "name": "some/blog",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "2.11",
    "symfony/cache": "^6.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "roave/security-advisories": "dev-latest",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^6.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

and trying to install `doctrine/data-fixtures` package

`$ composer require --dev doctrine/data-fixtures`

but got an error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.6 conflicts with doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.6.
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.5 conflicts with doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.5.
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.4 conflicts with doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.4.
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.3 conflicts with doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.3.
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.2 conflicts with doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.2.
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.1 conflicts with doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.1.
    - doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.0 conflicts with doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.0.
    - doctrine/orm is locked to version 2.11.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - Root composer.json requires doctrine/data-fixtures ^1.6 -> satisfiable by doctrine/data-fixtures[1.6.0, ..., 1.6.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

What does it mean that the dependency in some version conflicts with the same dependency in the same version? And how to resolve such an issue?

**UPD**: Thanks for Niko's answer the issue have solved by installing a newer version of the `doctrine/orm` package. According to the `doctrine/data-fixtures` repo, it conflicts with `doctrine/orm` [under 2.14 version](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/blob/1.6.x/composer.json#L23).

But why Composer's message is `doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.6 conflicts with doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.2.`? The proper one should be `doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.6 conflicts with doctrine/orm 2.11`.

Looks like it's a Composer's bug.

Comment: `doctrine/orm` in v2.11.0 is relatively old. Why not update it?

Comment: I just copied the package version from the current Doctrine ORM docs, Project setup section. Didn't think about its actuality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `doctrine/data-fixtures` v1.6.0 (released in Dec 2022), there's a incompability with `doctrine/orm` older than v2.12 (introduced in [PR 393](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/pull/393)).

You should either upgrade `doctrine/orm` to any more current version (keep in mind that v2.11.0 that you use is more than 18 months old!), or use an older version of `doctrine/data-fixtures`, like in this command:

```
composer require --dev doctrine/data-fixtures:"^1.5"
```

Comment: Thank you, Niko, your answer helped. Just opened a doctrine/data-fixtures repos and saw that it conflicts with the doctrine/orm version under 2.14th `"doctrine/orm": "<2.14"`. So after the update to the actual orm, fixtures have been installed successfully. But the message from Composer is still under question. The proper one should be ` doctrine/data-fixtures 1.6.6 conflicts with doctrine/orm 2.11.`, not one described in the current ticket.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section